# junit , Springboot , java , mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-test, spring-annotations

When I was writing test case using the Mockito and Junit, I was using the @InjectMocks for the class to be tested. In other parts of project, I also see @Autowired is being used for the class to be tested.

When can I use @InjectMocks and @Autowired? What is the difference between two when we are trying to use them with class to be tested?